# Stop video playback on Siri Remote Menu Button press

Tags: swift, avfoundation, tvos

In my application I do play a video with that function

```
func easyRandom_play(episodeTitle:String){
    self.backgroundMusic?.stop()
    backgroundMusic?.stop()
    let link = "http://46.235.26.87/\(__TITLENAME_FOLDERNAME_DOWNLOAD__)/\(episodeTitle).m4v"
    print(link)

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: link)!
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    } 
}
```

Now there is no way to stop the video - normally the menu button should take me back and end the playback.
Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle the Menu button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Setup Menu Button recognizer
    let menuGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleMenuGesture(_:)))
    menuGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuGesture)
}

func handleMenuGesture(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Menu Gesture")
    // Stop video and dismiss view controller here
}
```